# Can't Enter Image Url in SlideModel class in android studio

Tags: image, android-studio, class, slider

Hey I am new to Android Development.I was building an application where I had to use ImageSlider UI.After following a tutorial in youtube,I implemented the same code in which ImageSlider  was used.An array object of SlideModel class was created and image url was passed onto each item.I used this code inside multiple activities and ran my application.It worked perfectly.After a week,when I was building another application and I had to use the same code,I copied the same code into my application.But it was showing me error.Firstly,there were two fields in SlideModel class and both were strings.The setImageList() method of ImageSlider class had second parameter as a boolean but now it has changed to ScaleType.I somehow change the second argument for that method but I am confused in SlideModel class.It is giving me an error.I now some changes have been made in these built in classes which I am not able to figure out.I tried to search for official documentation of SlideModel class but it showed me no documentation.Can anybody tell me what are the fields of this class now.The same code worked fine without showing any error in my previous application.I have shared my code below.

```
public class ArchitectsAndDesigners extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageSlider slider;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_architects_and_designers);

        slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);

 List<SlideModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new SlideModel("",""));
        models.add(new SlideModel("",""));
        models.add(new SlideModel("",""));
        models.add(new SlideModel("",""));


        slider.setImageList(models, ScaleTypes.FIT);

    }
}
```

Can anyone tell what are the fields of SlideModel class now?Previously both were strings.There is no official documentation of this class.

Answer (score 0):

`This code works fine-------------

models.add(new SlideModel("","", ScaleTypes.FIT));`